# Google Analytics Campaign > Custom Campaign not showing on site

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I have some troubles in tracking Campaign in GA Android. 
If you use some campaign data on start of app all is ok and you will able to see Campaign on site, later. In logs i have something like this:

```
> Hit delivery requested: ht=1487674823933, _s=16, _v=ma9.2.56, aid=com.TestCmp.TestApp,
> an=TestApp, av=1.14.1, cc=test_content, cid=5917df3e-cc15-4314-861e-0eaa3c742c75,
> ck=test_term, cm=test_medium, cn=test_name , cs=test_source, ni=1, sr=1080x1776, t=data,
> tid=XX-XXXXXXXX-X, ul=en-us, v=1
```

But when you try to track campaign manually from code, by using Tracker.send(). Everything look fine(logs), but i wait about day and I couldnt see my Campaign on site. Seems like nothing happens and campaign didn`t tracked. Here is log from android studio:

```
> Hit delivery requested: ht=1487677206887, _s=6, _v=ma9.2.56, a=1570357627, aid=com.TestCmp.TestApp
> adid=444152c4-3228-444d-9a88-be47724bbe16, aip=0, an=TestApp, ate=1, av=1.14.1,
> cc=AndContent, cd=Sector, t=data, cid=2a130 fd4-438e-4db6-a8e1-38f064604efa, ck=AndTerm,
> cm=AndroidMedium, cn=SourceAndroid, cs=SourceAndroid, sf=100.0, sr=1080x1776, tid=XX-XXXXXXXX-X, ul=en-us, v=1
```

Here is the code that i am using to track Campaign manually. Tracking event and screens works fine. Trouble only with this case.

```
public static void ReportCampaign(String source, String campaign, String medium, String term, String content)
  {
    Map<String, String> paramsMap = new HashMap();
    SetMapParam(paramsMap, "&cs", source);
    SetMapParam(paramsMap, "&cn",   campaign);
    SetMapParam(paramsMap, "&cm", medium);
    SetMapParam(paramsMap, "&ck",term);
    SetMapParam(paramsMap, "&cc",content);

    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
    .setAll(paramsMap)
    .build());
  } 

public static void SetMapParam(Map map,String paramName, String paramValue) 
  {
    if (paramName == null) 
     {
       Log.w(LOG_TAG, "SetMapParam.set() called with a null paramName.");
       return;
     }
    map.put(paramName, paramValue != null ? paramValue : "");
  }
```

No errors or warnings in logs. iOS work correctly - everything tracks and you can see this data on site, but Android Campaigns doesnt work. If you have some ideas why this happens, it would be very helpful...

Comment: Does your GA view use a filter that excludes internal / test traffic?  Or is the ht parameter applying a time zone offset?

Comment: @AndrewC , no. We do not use any of those feature.

Comment: Ok, i realized my problems. You need wait about 2 days, to see your data on site... OMG...